# How to auto prefix with comment char when inserting code ref label with org-store-link

Tags: org-babel, comment, org-link

There is a way to link to a specific link of code in org babel src block. with `org-store-link`.

Here is an example:

```lisp
 ;;; This is comment | line. |
 (describe-char | (point)) ; | comment |
 (message | "hello, world") |
```

*NOTE*: The vertical bar (`|`) is the point positions.
I need a way to auto detect current position, whether it is in comment area.
If yes, then don't add comment char. If no, then auto add comment char like at
the third line.

An advice for elisp or some way else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;;; auto prefix with comment char when create code ref in src block with
;;; `org-store-link'.
(advice-add 'org-store-link :before #'comment-dwim)
```

Comment: This advice seems can work in most cases, but currently not work in `ob-clojure` src block. weird.